# Oracle SQL Script - Transpose data in pairs for subsequent records

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to transpose records by SQL Oracle Query:

```
Table1:

Col1
1
2
3
4
5
```

AS:

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

How is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lead()`:

```
select col1, col2
from (select col1, lead(col1) over (order by col1) as col2
      from t
     ) t
where col2 is not null;
```

If the values are really sequential numbers with no gaps, then you could use a `join`.